# Android: How to check if a DB field is blank and, if so, add a value like "Unnamed Record"?

Tags: android

I am working off the Android Notepad Tutorial as a base. The problem is that when someone creates a record with a null name field, it shows up as a blank space in the listview and is unclickable, and therefore undeletable from the list.

I would like to have the program check for a null "name" field and replace it with the string "Unnamed Record" so that it comes up appropriately in the listview. Everything that I have tried so far has not worked correctly.

Another possible solution might be the give the name field an initial value of "Unnamed Record" but I am not sure that this would be effective.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran over the same problem during the Notepad Tutorial. I solved it with setting a manual SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder to the SimpleCursorAdapter which connects the Cursor with the overview of notes:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, notesCursor, from, to);
    notes.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            if (cursor.getString(columnIndex).equals("")) {
                ((TextView) view).setText("no title");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    setListAdapter(notes);
```

The first and Last line (instantiation of the SimpleCursorAdapter and setListAdapter(notes) are out of the tutorial, the notes.setViewBinder(...) is what you need to replace empty Note Titles with your text (in the example its 'no title').

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure how you're doing this. could we see some code? If its an `edittext` that you're using to retrieve the text just check if what is returned is equal to null? If there's no way of checking the input directly one such solution would be to check the field itself when you're extracting it from the database.

E.g: when you're using a cursor to extract the value in field `name` just check if it's equal to null?

It's kind of hard to come up with a more specific answer without seeing some code.

Comment: Should I be looking at the DBadapter or the populatedata() method in the NoteEdit activity? Where in the code would it make the most sense to add this null check? I will add some relevant code snippets to my initial post.